# Printing a html file to PDF loses HTML formatting

Tags: safari, google-chrome, pdf, html

I have this standalone report in html. CSS styles are all embedded within the html itself.

[image]

When I tried to print to a pdf file, the pdf output becomes

[image]

I basically lost all the formatting in the html. Both chrome or safari produce the same result.

How can I get a PDF that preserves the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting for printing webpages is to try not printing extra images and colors to waste ink etc. Theres an option to print everything, see image below:

[image: Printer settings]

Let us know if this worked for you.